# How to build Linq Query setp by step to retrieve data from DBSet

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am building a dynamic query with some predicates, some may be a .Contains(), others a .StartsWith(), ...

But when I try to retrieve the entities I get a weird EF Core error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(t => Invoke(__predicate_0, t.EndsOn)
> )' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'

```
IQueryable<Api.Data.Models.Travel> query = _travelContext.Travels.AsQueryable();

foreach(var predicate in travelQuery.Predicates.StartDate)
    {
        query = query.Where(travel => predicate(travel.StartedOn));
    }

foreach (var predicate in travelQuery.Predicates.EndDate)
    {
        query = query.Where(travel => predicate(travel.EndsOn));
    }
var x = await query.ToListAsync();
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Comment: have you tried to make it return a `Func<>` instead of `bool`? entity framework cant translate your code into query as it has no idea what it do. that being said, you can avoid doing it on database at all by pulling everything to your app.

Comment: @BagusTesa, this seems like a great idea. I am currently trying to do so but struggling to make my extension methods return a Func/Predicate instead

Comment: hard to say given the use case of your predicate doesnt seem to reflect the code for the predicate you have provided.  our `AreNotNull` can be written `public static Func<DateTime?, DateTime?, bool> AreNotNull = (date1, date2) => date1 != null && date2 != null;` then can be used `query.Where(travel => AreNotNull(travel.StartDate, travel.EndDate))`. hopefully entity framework can translate those `Func` to proper query. i cant test it, dont have visual studio at hand atm.

Comment: You cannot do that with vanilla EF. Also everything should be `Expression<Func<>>`.  If you extend your question what is your predicates `travelQuery.Predicates.StartDate` probably I may help.

Comment: @BagusTesa, do not mix `IEnumerable` predicates and `IQueryable`. `Func<>` cannot help in creating filter for generating SQL.

Comment: yeah, sorry, my bad. i kind of forgot entity framework uses `Expression`. thanks for the warning.

Comment: That is not a weird EF Core error - that is an expected error when you attempt to use unsupported constructs in queries intended to be used with EF Core. EF Core translates queries into SQL, if you don't stay within what is supported for translation, you will get this error. Your sample code has no `Invoke` - where is the code that has `Invoke`?

Comment: PS Why are you using `AsQueryable()`? It is redundant with your declaration...

Comment: Consider using [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit).